# C++ dynamically define class member as either an object or a reference to another member

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, reference, constructor

Suppose I have a class as follows:

```
class Solution {    
public:    
    std::vector<double> x;
}
```

Suppose I have a function as follows:

```
void function(Solution& sol) {
    // do some calculations on the solution vector
}
```

Under some circumstances, I will want `function` to perform calculations directly using the vector `x`.  However, under some circumstances I will want to perform calculations using another vector that is produced by a mapping of the vector `x`.

Give these possible circumstances, it makes sense to introduce an additional member to the class `Solution`, but in the first circumstance this additional member will simply refer to `x`, and in the second circumstance this additional member will itself be another `std::vector` that is determined by a mapping of some form.

So, ideally I could add a ctor to `Solution` that creates/defines a member named `y` either as a `std::vector` or as merely a reference to `x`.  Then, my `function` could simply operate directly using `y`.

How might I do this?

Comment: Alter the function to take either `vector::iterator` or [`Boost::transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html)

Comment: @MooingDuck Interesting.  The problem with that, however, is that the mapping from `x` to `x_mapped` (say), is not a 1-to-1 mapping.

Comment: alright, well there's many many ways to skin this cat, do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your function as:

```
void function(std::vector<double>& x)
```

And pass different vectors to it, depending on circumstances

**Edit** Using references in ctors

```
class Solution 
{    
    std::vector<double> x;
    std::vector<double>& y; 
public:    
    Solution(std::vector<double>& _y) : y(_y) { }
    Solution() : y(x) { }
    void function() { /* do work on y*/ }    
};
```

This way your `function` always operates on the same reference, but you can control what data this reference refers to. Note that `x` and `y` are now private -- this ensures that these members are only used locally via `function()` method.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely a good suggestion.  The context of what I'm doing is taking an existing framework, and trying to modify temporarily one small part of it.  So, I might have to do what you're suggesting, but if I can do what I generally hinted at, then it would make my life easier.

Comment: Also, I'm interested in learning more about using references, so even as a purely academic question, I'm curious about the (perhaps convoluted) method I hinted at.

Comment: Edited the answer to include another possible solution

Comment: Would you explain what the two different ctors do?

Comment: The `Solution()` is a default constructor and it would initialize the `y` reference to a default data location -- `x`. The `Solution(std::vector<double>& _y)` constructor initializes the `y` reference to (point to) a custom data passed to the constructor as a parameter.

Comment: So, in the default ctor, `y(x)` basically causes `y` to be a reference to the data of `x`?